# Peterson's Algorithm of 2 processes mutex in critical section of shared memory

Tags: c, operating-system, shared-memory

I'm trying to use Peterson's Algorithm for two processes that mutex a critical section with shared memory. However, I kept getting segmentation fault. I use Ubuntu 20.04 to code this problem. Please tell me how I can fix this problem.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>

//Initiate variables
int flag[2];
int turn;
int* sharedMemory;

void lock_process(int procNum) {
    printf("lock_pr");
    flag[procNum] = 1;
        turn = 1 - procNum;
    while (flag[1 - procNum] == 1 && turn == 1 - procNum);
}

void unlock_process(int procNum) {
    printf("unlock_pr");
    flag[procNum] = 0;
}

void* switching(void* process) {
    int i = 0;
    int procNum = *(int*)process;
    printf("Thread Entered: %d\n", procNum);
    lock_process(procNum);
    for (i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        printf("switch_pr");
//      lock_process(procNum);
        (*sharedMemory)++;
//      unlock_process(procNum);    
    }
    unlock_process(procNum);
}

int main() {
    pthread_t t1, t2;
    flag[0] = 0;
    flag[1] = 0;
    turn = 0;
    sharedMemory = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
    if (sharedMemory == NULL) {
            perror("malloc error");
            exit(1);
        }
    *sharedMemory = 0;
    pthread_create(&t1, NULL, switching, (void*)0);
    pthread_create(&t2, NULL, switching, (void*)1);

    pthread_join(t1, NULL);
    pthread_join(t2, NULL);
    free(sharedMemory);
    return 0;
}
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Do note that Peterson's assumes appropriate atomicity and memory-ordering semantics for accesses to the control variables (your `flag` elements and `turn`).  Your implementation does not provide such.  As a result, there are multiple data races, leaving the behavior of your program undefined.  There is a fair chance that in practice, it will not reliably provide the intended mutual exclusion effect nor the intended access ordering for `*sharedMemory` (which are different, albeit related, things).

Answer (score 2):

The fourth parameter to `pthread_create` is intended to be a pointer to memory where there is data for the thread. The call  `pthread_create(&t2, NULL, switching, (void*)1);` does not pass a useful address. It attempts to convert an integer to a pointer.

To make use of that pointer, one would convert back to an `int`, as with `int procNum = (int) process;` instead of `int procNum = *(int*)process;`. The code in the question, `*(int*)process`, attempts to access memory at the address resulting from converting the integers 0 and 1, and this causes the segmentation fault.

However, to use the intended model, create an array with one element for each thread, initialize each element with the data for the thread, and pass the address of the element when creating the thread.

For example, for two threads, create an array with `int ProcessNumber[2] = { 0, 1 };` and pass `&ProcessNumber[i]` when creating thread number `i`.